# multiple entries + preserveModules with rollup and rollup-plugin-babel - why are all helpers not included in _rollupPluginBabelHelpers.js?

Tags: babeljs, rollupjs

So I have a library of JSX that I am transpiling for inclusion in a React project.

**Configs**

rollup.config.js: -

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel"
import pkg from "./package.json"

const externals = Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {})

export default [
  {
    input: __dirname + "/src/File1.js",
    output: {
      dir: __dirname + "/lib/",
      format: "esm",
    },
    plugins: [
      babel({}),
    ],
    preserveModules: true,
    external: externals
  },
  {
    input: __dirname + "/src/File2.js",
    output: {
      dir: __dirname + "/lib/",
      format: "esm",
    },
    plugins: [
      babel({})
    ],
    preserveModules: true,
    external: externals
  },
  ...
]
```

.babelrc (inside /src): -

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ],
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**The problem**

When I include the code in my webpack compiler, I get errors like these: -

```
WARNING in ./lib/File1.js 29:146-161 "export 'defineProperty' (imported as '_defineProperty') was not found in './_virtual/_rollupPluginBabelHelpers.js'

WARNING in ./lib/File2.js 45:11-25 "export 'objectSpread2' (imported as '_objectSpread2') was not found in './_virtual/_rollupPluginBabelHelpers.js'
```

It seems that providing an array of multiple entries results in a **_rollupPluginBabelHelpers.js** populated with only the helpers required for the final entry in the array.

Can anyone help me with this? I have read all the documentation I can find and googled and I can't find an answer to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been [resolved on github](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues/324) with the following config: -

```
export default {
    input: [__dirname + "/src/File1.js", __dirname + "/src/File2.js"],
    output: {
        dir: __dirname + "/lib/",
        format: "esm",
    },
    plugins: [
        babel({}),
    ],
    external: externals
}
```